# Help with a Vlookup function to return multiple results of not exact match

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, vlookup, regex

I am trying to run the following code to return all the matches of column A from column C in a set of rows. In this situation, cell A1, is contained in a few iterations of column C, however, these are not exact matches. i.e  I would want a match for this cell https://i.postimg.cc/FzHBMnVc/KENKD00319-03-KDLP0808-WHITE-3235.jpg as KDLP0808 is contained in the URL.

I am using the code below to do this

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,SMALL(IF("*"&A1&"*"=C:C,ROW(C:C)- MIN(ROW(C:C))+1,""),COLUMN()-4)), "")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=FILTER(C1:C, REGEXMATCH(C1:C, A1))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

You can try a quick query too (in case you need to test several condition in the future)

```
=QUERY(C:C,"SELECT * WHERE C CONTAINS 'KDLP0808'")
```

or

```
=QUERY(C:C,"SELECT * WHERE C CONTAINS '"&A1&"'")
```

Keep in mind that the QUERY function may not be the best solution in your case.